# Ball with euclidean metric - mistake in book?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, the ball with euclidean metric $d_{l_2}$ is defined, in terence tao's analysis vol II, as:

$$B_{(\mathbb{R}^2,d_{l_2})}((0,0),1) = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 <1\}$$

Since euclidean metric is such that $$d(x,y) = ((x-y)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Shouldn't this be :

$$B_{(\mathbb{R}^2,d_{l_2})}((0,0),1) = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : [(x-0)^2+ (y-0)^2]^{\frac{1}{2}} <1\}$$
$$= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : (x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}<1\}$$

Comment: The Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $$d(x,y) = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n (x_k -y_k)^2}.$$

Comment: yes, I was taking $n=1$, sorry that I didn't clarify.

Comment: But Tao speaks of $n = 2$.

Comment: I was just a little bit lazy, but in $n=2$ I do not see how it is correct? We should be taking the square root of $x^2+y^2$ should we not?

Comment: Please think: Where is the difference between the two definitions? Are there any points which are in the first set and not in the second and viceversa?

Comment: You're right, instead of $x^2+y^2\lt1$ it should be $x^2+y^2\lt1^2.$

Comment: @bof thanks, I didn't realise haha.

Comment: @bof very nice :D +1

Comment: @bof: Somehow I think I know why we will certainly soon hit a hundred thousand questions with no answer. =P

Comment: lol i feel bullied to be honest.